# SQL server transaction visibility issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

When I execute the following code (**Case 1**) I get the value 2 for the count. Which means inside the same transaction the chagnes made to the table are visible. So this behaves in the way I expect.

**Case 1**

```
begin tran mytran
begin try

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ft](
    [ft_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ft_Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FileType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ft_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ft]([ft_Name])
VALUES('xxxx')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ft]([ft_Name])
VALUES('yyyy')

select count(*) from [dbo].[ft]

commit tran mytran
end try
begin catch
rollback tran mytran
end catch
```

However when I alter a column (e.g. add a new column within the transaction) it is not visible to the (self/same) transaction (**Case 2**). Let's assume there is a product table without a column called ft_ID and I am adding a column withing the same transaction and going to read it.

**Case 2**

```
begin tran mytran
begin try

IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM   sys.columns 
  WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Products') 
         AND name = 'ft_ID'
)
begin
alter table dbo.Products 
add ft_ID int null
end

select ft_ID from dbo.Products


commit tran mytran
end try
begin catch
rollback tran mytran
end catch
```

When trying to execute **Case 2** I get the error "Invalid column name 'ft_ID'" because the newly added column is not visible within the same transaction.

Why this discrepancy happens? Create table is atomic (**Case 1**) and works in the way I expect but alter table  is not. Why changes made within the same transaction are not visible to the statements down (**Case 2**).

Answer (score 2):

You get a *compile* errors. The batch is never launched into execution. See [Understanding how SQL Server executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/). Transaction visibility and boundaries has nothing to do with what you're seeing.

You should always separate DDL and DML into separate requests. Without going into too much details, due to the way recovery works, mixing DDL and DML in the same transaction is just asking for trouble. Just take my word on this one.

Comment: Can you explain why Case 1 works but why case 2 fails. Why Micosoft has design it in that way? I feel this is inconsistent. What is the technical explanation?

Comment: There are rules for batches. One of them is you can't change table and reference new columns in the same batch, as stated in the other answer. Case 1: table created, this is allowed. Case 2: table altered, this is NOT allowed.

Comment: @SriwanthaSriAravinda: 'Is a compilation error' **is** the technical explanation. Read the article linked to understand the technical explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> Rules for Using Batches
>   ... 
>   A table cannot be changed and then the new columns referenced in the same batch.

[See this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Alternative is to spawn a child batch and reference your new column from there, like...

```
exec('select ft_ID from dbo.Products')
```

However, as Remus said, be very careful about mixing schema changes and selecting data from that schema, especially in one same transaction. Even WITHOUT transaction this code will have side-effects: try wrapping this exec() workaround in the stored procedure, and you will get a recompile every time you call it. Tough luck, but it simply works that way.